# how to make a fql query in java

Tags: java, facebook-fql

Hy,

I want to make a fql query on stream table.The code is:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT source_id"+
            ",created_time,permalink FROM stream WHERE  and"+
            " source_id=.. limit 1000 & access_token=...");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFields());
    System.out.println("=== Content ===");
    while (((c = responseStream.read()) != -1)) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
```

In browser if i type this url it works but in my code doesnt work only if i but some characters like: %20%20 ...is there any way to write the url in my code without this?

Answer (score 0):

You must perform URL encoding: `URLEncoder.encode(url)`. This is required by HTTP spec. The URL will be decoded automatically at server side, so the application will get it in "pure" form.